# Mac OS X sleep mode

Tags: macbook, sleep, power-management

I am a new Mac user. I need to return to the MacBook continuously with varying amounts of time in between.

However, the Mac goes into sleep mode breaking the tasks it was doing. I have figured out how to avoid having to renter password all the time, but it is still annoying. Is there to:

- Have longer time pass before it sleeps?
- Instead of sleep, just throttle down? (like shutdown screen, shutoff a core etc.)
- And finally, when closing the macbook, go into most sleep/powersave mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the *Energy Saver* preferences?

[image]

You can set it so it never goes to sleep and just stops the hard drives if possible. You can also dim the screen (on a MacBook) or sleep the display after a specified amount of time.

When closing the MacBook, it will always go to sleep.